# Error using Flash ExternalInterface

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript

I'm trying to pass data from Flash to Javascript via `ExternalInterface`.
It works fine when I'm testing on my localhost, but when I tried to set a website at IIS, so my coworkers could test my application, like: *http://192.168.0.10/MyApp*, I getting this error:

> Error calling method on NPObject.

After reading some questions at Stackoverflow I tried to set  `allowScriptAccess="always"` at my embed tags and `Security.allowDomain(*)` at my AS file, but it still doesn't work.

I'm using [swf object](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) if that matters.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**: The error occurs when I try to call a method **from** js to my **swf**. This is the code adapted to the answer bellow.

```
var swfReady = false;
swfobject.embedSWF("swf/1.swf", "flashContent", "300", "250", "11", "expressInstall.swf", null, { allowScriptAccess: "always" } , null, function (e) {
    if (e.success) {
         setTimeout(function () {
              swfReady = true;
         }, 150);
    }
});

btnConfig.on('click', function () {

    if (swfReady) {
         flashContent.myMethod();
    } else {
         alert("Hold on...");
    }

});
```

This works great at **localhost** but when someone try to view the same page through my IP, I get the Javascript error `Error calling method on NPObject`.

Comment: Check that you have done `Security.allowDomain("*");` before your `ExternalInterface` call

Comment: I'm setting it at the constructor of my as3 class. Is that right?

Comment: Is the SWF file on the same domain as the HTML page where it's embedded?

Comment: Yes, it is!
My page is at http://localhost and the swf at http://localhost/swf

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this happens when the swf is not ready. You can try the callback function in embedSWF. Don't invoke any swf method until this callback. In addition to this sometimes you will need a few milliseconds of delay.

```
swfobject.embedSWF("sample.swf", "swfdiv", "400", "300", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", null, null, null, function (e) {
    if (e.success) {
        console.log("swf ready ");
        setTimeout(function(){
            // call swf method here
        }, 150);
    } else {
        console.log("embedding failed");
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried to put all my binds inside the callback, so if I click the button before the swf is ready it would do nothing. That didn't work...

Comment: Add one javascript function and invoke it using **ExternalInterface.call** to make sure that ExternalInterface is working.

Comment: I did that, and it's working. What doesn't work is the other way around, using **ExternalInterface.addCallback**

Comment: @Diode: you don't really need to invoke a function to see if ExternalInterface works. The Boolean value in `ExternalInterface.isAvailable` does that for you

Comment: @AlexFigueiredo: What happens to the callBack? Do you get an error? Maybe you could edit your question to add that

Comment: The error I get is already at my question: **Error calling method on NPObject**. This is a Javascript error that occours when I try to invoke a method of my swf object. I'll edit the question to show the code.

Comment: @AlexFigueiredo: Okay. So do one thing. Call a javascript function from actionscript using **ExternalInterface.call** and from that javascript function invoke the method in actionscript. This is a method that we usullay use to identify the issue. If possible please share your javascript code.